# What does comparator return really mean in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, stable-sort

I am trying to do stable sort in C++ and my array is like this

> {{first = "art zero", second = "let3 "}, {first = "own kit dig", second = "let2 "}, {first = "art can", second = "let1 "}}

```cpp
sort(let.begin(), let.end(),
[](pair<string,string>& a, pair<string,string>& b) {
    int comp = a.first.compare(b.first);
    if(!comp) {
        return a.second.compare(b.second);
    } else {
        return comp;
    }
});
```

Why it did not sort lexicographically for the first value? And what does the return value really mean in C++ comparator? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply choose [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) as your container, the default ordering provides storage in lexical sort order, e.g.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main (void) {
    
    std::map<std::string, std::string> let {{"art zero", "let3 "}, 
                                            {"own kit dig", "let2 "},
                                            {"art can", "let1 "}};
    for (const auto& p : let)
        std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/map_sort_lex
art can, let1
art zero, let3
own kit dig, let2
```

**Sorting On Both You Cannot Use `map/mutimap`**

If you must sort telegraphically on both `.first` and `.second` you cannot use `std::map/std::multimap`. They are limited to sorting on `.first` for storage. An alternative is a `std::vector<std::pair<>>` with your pairs of strings.

You can implement your custom compare by writing a simple `bool` [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) function as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool lexcmp (const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& lhs, 
             const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.first != rhs.first)
        return lhs.first < rhs.first;
    
    return lhs.second < rhs.second;
}

int main (void) {
    
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> let {{"art zero", "let3 "}, 
                                                          {"art zero", "let2 "},
                                                          {"own kit dig", "let2 "},
                                                          {"art can", "let1 "}};
    
    std::sort (let.begin(), let.end(), lexcmp);
    
    for (const auto& p : let)
        std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

After adding an additional `"art zero", "let2 "` pair to force the sort on `.second`, you would have:

```
$ ./bin/vector_sort_lex
art can, let1
art zero, let2
art zero, let3
own kit dig, let2
```

If you can get away with only sorting on `.first`, then `std::map` (or `std::multimap`) handle the sorting for you. To sort on both `.first` and `.second`, then the solution above isn't bad either.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) and [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) already provide lexicographical ordering by default so **you don't need to write a compare function** for this task.

If you do want to write a compare function it must satisfy the [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements. It must provide a *strict weak ordering*. That means it returns `true` if the first value appears before the second and `false` otherwise.

You can fix your code so it returns `true` for "less than" and `false` otherwise.

```
sort(let.begin(), let.end(), [](const pair<string,string> &a, const pair<string,string> &b){
    int comp = a.first.compare(b.first);
    if (comp == 0) {
        return a.second.compare(b.second) < 0; // less than (ascending order)
    } else
        return comp < 0; // less than (ascending order)
});
```